# Adding multiple SSL certificates in apache AWS

Tags: php, apache, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Here is the architecture 
I have an EC2 instance , 2 web domains, Load Balancer.

the 2 domains are pointing toward the same Load Balancer and the load balancer has an EC2 Instance on it.

I have c1 on the load balancer and in apache config as well.

Since both domains are pointing to same server , I want to use different cert on that server , so when I do abc.com or def.com , I should get https certified .

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the two certificates like this:

```
cat first_crt.crt second_crt.crt > two_certs.crt
```

And then add it to the listener security settings.